# How to peek on an Optional?

Tags: java, option-type

I want to use the fluent api of `Optional` and apply two `Consumer`s to it.

I'm dreaming about something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(key)
    .map(Person::get)
    .ifPresent(this::printName)
    .ifPresent(this::printAddress); // not compiling, because ifPresent is void
```

How do I apply several `Consumer`s to an `Optional`?

Comment: Just as a notice [a link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8175129) to a feature request ticket for java about exactly this topic which is marked as `won't fix`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
ofNullable(key)
    .map(Person::get)
    .map(x -> {printName(x);return x;})
    .map(x -> {printAddress(x);return x;});
```

Answer (score 50):

Here's how you can implement the missing `peek` method for `Optional`:

```
<T> UnaryOperator<T> peek(Consumer<T> c) {
    return x -> {
        c.accept(x);
        return x;
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
Optional.ofNullable(key)
    .map(Person::get)
    .map(peek(this::printName))
    .map(peek(this::printAddress));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I like, that it clearly shows the intention. And if `.peek()` get's added to java in a later version, it is easy to refactor!

Comment: I like it, it works kind of like `Stream#peek` does.

Comment: Since Java9 you can use `Optional.stream().peek(Consumer<T>)`

Comment: The downside is that once you switch to a `Stream`, you can't go back to `Optional`

Answer (score 17):

With the new [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) method in the Optional API as of JDK9, you can invoke the `stream` method to transform from `Optional<T>` to `Stream<T>` which then enables one to `peek` and then if you want to go back to the `Optional<T>` just invoke `findFirst()` or `findAny()`.

an example in your case:

```
Optional.ofNullable(key)
        .map(Person::get) // Optional<Person>
        .stream() // Stream<Person>
        .peek(this::printName)
        .peek(this::printAddress)
        ...
```

Comment: Great idea! However a terminal operation (like `findFirst()`, `findAny()`, `collect(...)` or similar) is necessary, isn't it?

Comment: So maybe `... .peek(this::printName) .findAny().ifPresent(this::printAddress);` would be the best fit for my use-case.

Comment: @slartidan you don't need to add the `ifPresent` just `Optional.ofNullable(key)
        .map(Person::get) 
        .stream()
        .peek(this::printName)
        .peek(this::printAddress).findAny();` should suffice for your case

Answer (score 12):

While this may not seem very elegant, I would just combine both methods into one `lambda` and pass that to `ifPresent`:

```
ofNullable(key)
    .map(Person::get)
    .ifPresent(x -> {printName(x); printAddress(x);});
```

Alternatively, you could also use `andThen` to chain multiple consumers, although this would require you to cast the method reference to `Consumer`, which is not very elegant either.

```
ofNullable(key)
    .map(Person::get)
    .ifPresent(((Consumer) this::printName).andThen(this::printAddress));
```

Comment: I like you approaches a bit better then mine, because it makes it more *obvious* /readable what is actually happening (two actions, being executed after another).

Answer (score 11):

Java 8 alternative (`map` + `orElseGet`):

```
Optional.ofNullable(key)
        .map(Person::get) // Optional<Person>
        .map(Stream::of)  // Optional<Stream<Person>>
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty) // Stream<Person>
        .peek(this::printName)
        .peek(this::printAddress)
        .findAny();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(key)
        .map(Person::get)
        .ifPresent(combine(this::printAddress, this::printWish));
```

where `combine` is:

```
public <T> Consumer<T> combine(Consumer<T>... cs) {
  return x -> Stream.of(cs).peek(c -> c.accept(x)).close();
}
```

Comment: It is pretty similar to `((Consumer) this::printName).andThen(this::printAddress)`, but I like the varargs aspect of it (allowing any number of consumers).

Comment: Also you can take consumers as param from some external source and if you using `andThen`, you have to unwrap consumers and build `andThen` chain manually.

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1+ we have support for [experimental **@ExtensionMethod** annotation of *Lombok* project](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod) (and Lombok-plugin installed as a default plugin in IDEA 2020.3+). So, in case that you use both of it instruments in your project, that problem can be solved a little bit easier. We have to:

1. ...write class *our.main.pkg*.common.**OptionalUtils** with extension-method "peek"
2. ...annotate our class with **@ExtensionMethod** annotation and our **OptionalUtils** class as a value for "value" param
3. ...use peek method.

**OptionalUtils** code (actually, I used **[JetBrains annotation library](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations)** for making code more understandable):

```
package our.main.pkg.common;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

@UtilityClass
public class OptionalUtils {

  @NotNull
  @Contract(pure = true)
  public <T> Optional<T> peek(@NotNull Optional<T> self,
                              @NotNull Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return self.map(t -> {
      consumer.accept(t);
      return t;
    });
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
package our.main.pkg;

import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.experimental.ExtensionMethod;
import our.main.pkg.common.common.OptionalUtils;

@ExtensionMethod(OptionalUtils.class)
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String... __) {
    Optional.ofNullable(key)
        .map(Person::get)
        .peek(this::printName)
        .ifPresent(this::printAddress);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your response. I prefer the "vanilla java" out-of-the-box approaches (only my personal preference). But: I never knew, that classes can be extended this way (I've seen this in C#, but never in java) and it therefore is an interesting and valuable contribution!

Comment: This feature is natively supported in lots of languages in JVM platform - in Scala, Kotlin and Groovy, for example. So, according to this (and for C#, as you say), we can call it a good practice in Java too! ;)