# Why does Optional not provide a peek method?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type, java-9

I'm curious to know why Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) does not provide a `peek` method similar to [`Stream`'s one](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)).

The `peek` method [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) of the `Stream` interface states:

> - @apiNote This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline

This almost exactly describes my use case:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User getUserById(long id) {
    return repository.findById(id)
        .peek(u -> logger.debug("Found user = {} by id = {}", u, id))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id));
}
```

(`repository.findById` returns `Optional<User>` (see [CrudRepository#findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findById-ID-)))

But it won't compile since there is no `peek` method on `Optional`.

So without the `peek` method everything above transforms to:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User getUserById(long id) {
  Optional<User> userOptional = repository.findById(id);
  if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
    logger.debug("Found user = {} with id = {}", userOptional.get(), id);
  }
  return userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id));
}
```

It is also possible to do something like this (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992252/6486622)):

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
public abstract class OptionalUtils {
    public static <T> UnaryOperator<T> peek(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        return t -> {
            consumer.accept(t);
            return t;
        };
    }
}
```

And use it with the `map` method:

```
return repository.findById(id)
    .map(OptionalUtils.peek(u -> logger.debug("Found user = {} with id = {}", u, id)))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id));
```

But I think this is a hack rather than clean usage of `Optional`.

Since Java 9 it is possible to transform `Optional` to `Stream` but the stream does not have the `orElseThrow` method (and obviously it should not).

Also it is possible to do the same using [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)) but it returns `void`. (And for me it seems that `ifPresent` should not return anything other than `void`)

Am I misusing `Optional`?

Is the absence of the `peek` method intentional? (But at the same time Vavr's [`Option`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html) does provide the [`peek`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) method.)

Or it was just considered not worth it?

Comment: Probably because its designers considered it wasn't worth it, and having `ifPresent()` was enough.

Comment: I don't see any reduction in readability if you use, instead of your construct, `User user = repository.findById().orElseThrow(...); logger.debug("...", user, id); return user` - Just three lines, the value gets logged if it existed. If this is the use case, it's no wonder the designers thought it's superfluous.

Comment: with java9 you can do `repository.findById(id).stream().peek(...).findAny().orElseThrow(...)`, but it's still a hackish way to accomplish what you want.
The question is definitely worth an upvote, and I wish a proper answer too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, only the designers could answer you the "exact" details as to why there was no peek method for Optionals.

So, for now, you're stuck with using `isPresent()` which actually seems just fine in my view:

```
if (userOptional.isPresent()) 
    logger.debug("Found user = {} with id = {}", userOptional.get(), id);
```

or you could consider the suggested answers on the linked page if you want it as part of the pipeline.

btw, given the new `stream` method as of JDK9 you could do:

```
return repository.findById(id) // Optional<User>
                 .stream()  // Stream<User>
                 .peek(u -> logger.debug("Found user = {} by id = {}", u, id)) // Stream<User>
                 .findFirst() // Optional<User>
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id))
```

[see this answer for a similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737212/how-to-peek-on-an-optional/53581054#53581054).

Comment: Using ifPresent() would be more elegant: no need to call get().

Comment: Another way to write your last snippet (even in Java 8) would be `return repository.findById(id).flatMap(u -> Stream.of(u).peek(u2 -> logger.debug(...)).findFirst()).orElseThrow(...);`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner a bit more difficult to read but yeah that's a good shout!.

Answer (score 8):

There is already the [`Optional::ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) method that accepts a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

In Java 8, the only way is to use [`Optional::map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), to map the entity to itself and use it as `peek` method:

```
return repository.findById(id)
                 .map(u -> {
                     logger.debug("Found user = {} with id = {}", u, id)
                     return u;
                 })
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id));
```

... which shall be simplified implementing an own `peek` method:

```
<T> UnaryOperator<T> peek(Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return t -> {
        consumer.accept(t);
        return t;
    };
}
```

... and used comfortably with [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
return repository.findById(id)
                 .map(this.peek(logger.debug("Found user = {} with id = {}", u, id)))
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("id = " + id));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already `Optional::ifPresent` and `Optional::isPresent` method to log the result. 
But you probably want something in line. Answer to that is probably oversight.