# How to chain Optional ifPresent calls?

Tags: java, option-type

Suppose you have an Optional and you want to consume the Optional multiple times.
You could now save the Optional to a variable; and then use `ifPresent` two times on it:

```java
Optional<Animal> optionalAnimal = animalService.getAllAnimals().findFirst();
optionalAnimal.ifPresent(Animal::eat);
optionalAnimal.ifPresent(Animal::drink);
```

Another solution would be to ditch method references and use a lambda that does both:

```java
animalService.getAllAnimals().findFirst()
    .ifPresent(animal -> {
        animal.drink();
        animal.eat();
    });
```

If I have control over the class that is used in the Optional, I could simply change the methods to use a factory like pattern. So that `animal.drink()` would return itself.
Then I could write:

```java
animalService.getAllAnimals().findFirst()
    .map(Animal::drink)
    .ifPresent(Animal::eat);
```

But this would be semantically weird. And I don’t always have control over every class that I use in Optionals. And some classes are final, so I could not even extend them to have a factory styled method.

Furthermore, the Optional class is also final, so extending Optional itself is no option either.
All of this makes very little sense to me. `ifPresent()` returns void. If `ifPresent()` returned the Optional itself (similar to `peek()` for streams) it would be closer to my goal.

Is there another solution that I did not think of?

---

What I would like to have is something like this:

```java
animalService.getAllAnimals().findFirst()
    .ifPresent(Animal::drink)
    .ifPresent(Animal::eat);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but other languages have what are called "for comprehensions" for stuff like this. (Just FYI.)

Comment: Create a private method that calls both: `eatAndDrink`, then `blah().ifPresent(this::eatAndDrink)`

Comment: Your wish is for a builder pattern that doesn't build - that is weird imo. Why don't you like the lambda? It does exactly what one could expect: work with the result of the optional and the optional "wrapper" is no longer involved at that time.

Comment: I think in Java the lambda is the way to go, but I agree that it does not look elegant.

Comment: You could use the ["missing `peek()` method from this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992252/5515060)

Comment: @cyberbrain The builder pattern is just one of several patterns that chain method calls on the same object. No one said that chaining like that has to build something :) I do agree that I don't see anything wrong with the lambda though.

Comment: @cyberbrain I think they probably meant the [Fluent Interface Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), which the builder pattern is somewhat a part of

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [`Consumer.andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html#andThen(java.util.function.Consumer))

As alternative, you can introduce a method that allows to combine multiple Consumers using `Consumer.andThen()` and then perform all required side-effects by passing an aggregated Consumer into `Optional.ifPresent()`.

That's how such method might look like (credits to *@Lino* for the idea with the first Consumer as an *identity*):

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Consumer<T> combine(Consumer<T> first, Consumer<T>... others) {
    
    return Arrays.stream(others).reduce(first, Consumer::andThen);
}
```

*Usage example:*

```
animalService.getAllAnimals()
    .ifPresent(combine(Animal::drink, Animal::eat));
```

Comment: Could may be optimized to change the signature to `combine(Consumer<T> first, Consumer<T>... others)` that way you could use the `first` to pass as the identity to the `reduce()` method. This also disallows accidental calling of `combine()` without any parameters

Comment: If only Java allowed calling methods directly on the method reference without a cast to the functional interface :) Could have been `Animal::drink.andThen(Animal::eat)`.

Comment: @marstran *If only Java allowed* - as you've said it's not possible unless there would be a cast `((Consumer<Animal>)Animal::drink).andThen(Animal::eat);`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko: You are now aware of all the possible solutions.  If none of them meet your standards, then there may just be no solution that meets your standards.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I wasn't rejecting any, I'm not the OP.

Comment: @marstran woah that would be really cool. I didn’t even know that you can cast method references.

Comment: @DarioViva We can cast Lambdas and Method references as any other regular objects.  E.g. `((Consumer<Animal>) Animal::drink).andThen(Animal::eat).andThen(Animal::foo).andThen(Animal::bar)`. Casting is needed because the compiler knows only aggregated target type, but fails to infer the type of individual references (they have **no type** by itself, see [*more detailed explanation here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74479205/17949945)). In this chain, the first reference is typed via *Casting context*, the rest via *Invocation context* (because `andThen()` expects a `Consumer`).

Answer (score 0):

## Build a wrapper

Your idea of inheritance had a small flaw as you found out for yourself, but composition should be favoured in most cases anyway, so you could simply build a wrapper for `Optional` that does what you want:

### `FluentOptional`

```java
package examples.stackoverflow.q74467465;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class FluentOptional<T> {

  private final Optional<T> optional;

  public FluentOptional(Optional<T> optional) {
    this.optional = optional;
  }

  public static <S> FluentOptional<S> of(Optional<S> optional) {
    return new FluentOptional<>(optional);
  }

  public FluentOptional<T> ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
    this.optional.ifPresent(consumer);
    return this;
  }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```java
FluentOptional.of(animalService.getAllAnimals().findFirst())
    .ifPresent(Animal::drink)
    .ifPresent(Animal::eat);
```